# Building WPF/XAML applications in Nemerle

Tags: wpf, nemerle

What's the process for building WPF apps in languages other than C#/VB, spefically Nemerle? Are there any command line tools available that can compile XAML and embed it into an assembly?

Are there command-line tools for using .NET languages other than C#/VB with WPF, so that I can manually compile the XAML myself without having to go through the IDE? For example, if I wrote an WPF app in say, Nemerle, how would you use Nemerle as the codebehind language for WPF?

Comment: Too general.  SO is for specific questions.

Comment: It seems quite specific to me. "Are there any command line tools available ..." etc.

Comment: This isn't a question. It's an excuse for not wanting to Google "<language> WPF", where <language> is *any* CLR language other than VB or C#.

Comment: I googled "Nemerle WPF", and there are no results that actually show how to use it with Nemerle. That is why I'm asking on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For nemerle there is no XAML support for Visual studio yet.

Comment: I'm aware that Nemerle doesn't have XAML support in the IDE yet, and that's why I'm asking this question in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

F# and WPF have support in Visual Studion, e.g: [F# WPF Form – the basics](http://geekswithblogs.net/MarkPearl/archive/2010/06/10/f-wpf-form-ndash-the-basics.aspx) or [Learning WPF with F#](http://jyliao.blogspot.com/2007/10/learning-wpf.html) or just [Google "F# WPF"](http://www.google.co.il/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=f#%20wpf). Example for Boo: [Boo and WPF](http://devrants.blog.com/tag/boo/)